# Measures DAX in Excel

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I created a DAX Measure in Excel. I need to sum pieces sold for only certain products within one company.
I created a Pivot table with Companies' codes in a column A. And created a DAX measure:

```
CALCUALTE(
SUM('Sales'[Sold,pieces]),
FILTER('Sales',
'Sales'[Product]="Apples"&&'Sales'[Product]="Peaches")
)
```

This Measure does not work for multiple products, but for one product works.
Where is a mistake?

Please assist me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the boolean operator used in the measure. The `&&` means AND, therefore the filter is checking for the product that are Apples AND Peaches. What we want instead are products that are Apples OR Peaches. The OR operator is the double pipleline: `||`

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Sales'[Sold,pieces] ),
    FILTER (
        'Sales',
        'Sales'[Product] = "Apples"
            || 'Sales'[Product] = "Peaches"
    )
)
```

Comment: Not exactly. In this measure, I need to have a total sum of sold pieces of certain products. For instance, my shops sell bananas, oranges, apples and peaches. But i need to get a total sum of sold pieces only for apples and bananas within every shop.

Comment: Then you might just implement the measure like SUM( 'Sales'[Sold,pieces]), then select the products using the multiple choice in the filter panel of the pivot and put the shops on the rows. Otherwise, if the products to be selected are fixed, the measure with the OR does exactly what you ask, when inserted in a pivot with the shops on the rows.

Comment: I found a solution:

Answer (score -2):

```
CALCULATE (
SUM ('Sales'[Sold,pieces] ),
SWITCH ('Sales'[Product],
"Apples",TRUE(),
"Peaches",TRUE(),
FALSE()
))
```

Comment: I know this is a self-answer, but code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].